# averagedAPI Data in React 'has already been declared

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep getting the SyntaxError: Identifier 'averageGrade' has already been declared.  Here's the code at the top pertaining to the new function (everything was working until now).

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
    const [averageGrade, setGrade] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
    function fetchStudents() {
      fetch("api.location.address")
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();

        })
        .then(function (data) {
          setStudentList(data.students);
          setFilteredStudent(data.students);
          setGrade(data.grades);
        });
    }
    fetchStudents()
  }, []);
```

here's the thing I can't quite figure out. I've put inside the setGrade([]) 'grades', 'setGrade', 'averageGrade' as well as left it empty as shown...

```
const averageGrade = grades => grades.reduce((acc,v) => acc + v) / grades.length;
    setGrade([]);

return ( 
    <Wrapper>
      <h1 className="title">STUDENTS</h1>
        <input onChange = {filterStudents}/>
      {filteredStudents.map((students) => (
        <StudentCard
          key={students.id}
          grades={students.setGrade}
        />
      ))}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Please forgive me if the error is blatantly obvious to you. I did search for the solution and I'm just slamming my head against the desk now.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the complete block,

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
    const [averageGrade, setGrade] = useState([]);
    const [filteredStudent, setFilteredStudent] = useState([]);
    const [studentList, setStudentList] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
    function fetchStudents() {
      fetch("api.location.address")
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();

        })
        .then(function (data) {
          setStudentList(data.students);
          setFilteredStudent(data.students);

          let avgGrade = grades => grades.reduce((acc,v) => acc + v) / grades.length;// create a local variable, do not set averageGrade directly

          setGrade(avgGrade);
        });
    }
    fetchStudents()
  }, []);

return ( 
    <Wrapper>
      <h1 className="title">STUDENTS</h1>
        <input onChange = {filterStudents}/>
      {filteredStudents.map((students) => (
        <StudentCard
          key={students.id}
          grades={students.setGrade}
        />
      ))}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you! That did it!